# Python: pyplot - plot smooth curves with less clutter and show data points on the curve

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I have three lists of float values and each of these lists are pretty lengthy For example each has 250-300 elements. I managed to plot using following code but unfortunately its really hard to read after putting all these lists in one plot.

Here is sample of my list:

```
list1 = [0.607,0.157,0.242.............]
list2 = [0.992,0.296,0.237.............]
list3 = [0.231,0.079,0.256.............]
```

Highest possible value of any of these elements is 1.0

Here is the segment of my code: I didn't put my entire code because it has unnecessary section where I construct these lists while iterating over multiple vectors.

```
plt.plot(list1, 'ro')
plt.plot(list2, 'bo')
plt.plot(list3, 'go')
plt.ylabel('cosine values')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is how my current plot looks like]

This is how my current plot look like.

Comment: So how do you imagine condensing this more? Plotting a line would be just as cluttered. Did you experiment with making your points transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions, not sure if they comprise an answer, but here goes.

Try using `'.'` instead of `'o'` so the points take up less area

Since data seems to be condensed at the bottom, try plotting with a log scale `yscale('log')`

```
plt.plot(list1, 'r.')
plt.plot(list2, 'b.')
plt.plot(list3, 'g.')
plt.ylabel('cosine values')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

You also might want to consider reducing the number of data points through subsampling or averaging.

Comment: can you provide an example of yscale('log')